# What's the best way to replace titles with links to other posts?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a post model that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'title', unique = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    content = models.TextField(blank = True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now = True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', args = [self.slug])
```

When I render the post in a template I would like to replace all mentions of a post title with a link to that post (e.g. if I have a post entitled 'foo' and another posts' content has 'foo' it will be replaced with a link to the post).
For that I have written the following simple template tag (uses [django-classy-tags](http://django-classy-tags.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)):

```
class LinkBack(Tag):
    options = Options(
        Argument('posts', required = True),
        'for',
        Argument('content', required = True)
    )

    def render_tag(self, context, posts, content):
        output = content

        for post in posts:
            output = output.replace(post.title, '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (post.get_absolute_url() , post.title))

        return output
```

However I fear that this is going to slow down my website when there are many posts.
Is there a way to optimize that loop?
I could hook it to the pre_save signal but that will only link to existing posts and it feels like I am violating the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.
What's the best way to do it?

EDIT:
Should I be doing this in a cron job? That way I won't need to deal with the performance issue, however I am still violating SOC here since this is not the data's problem.

Comment: Where in your project have you noticed slowdowns caused by this?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: This is still in development but I've entered many posts to check this.

Comment: You could think about doing it with Javascript, after the post page loads. Just grab your post titles with an ajax call (out of a cache), then search the existing page and replace as needed.

Comment: @Grant: Won't it block the loading as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in time this will become even more expensive as the number of posts increase. But, there's a much better approach to have this done. When you consider the use case, you need to know the exact post title for this to work. So, if your already browsing around your site to get the exact title of some post, you should inevitably also come across the post's URL, right? What your doing is creating a clever mechanism that will take raw post titles and magically render them as references to an existing post on your site, but what you should be doing is creating an explicit reference as the post author and defer from any unnecessary post-processing.

Implement support for creating references, be it other posts or some other resources, located on your website or somewhere else. SO, for instance, uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for creating references via the syntax `[Title][#]` pointing to the list `[#]: http://path.to`, but there are many others. I know there are many questions relating to markup languages, some with editors in Django specifically, so I'm sure you can settle on something and have it plugged into your Django instance in no time.

Comment: But I can't possibly remember all the posts I made.

Comment: Just saying you should take something which already provides referencing support, what your trying to do, and give the power to the content author, not the system, to create those references. Current state: the system is building upon the content, your posts are presented once processed through a `LinkBack` tag, for each request your iterating through the post content once for every post that exists in your system. For what? What your trying to do is clever, but unintuitive, and I'm mostly concerned whether it's useful enough to justify all of this. Just keep it simple and use a markup editor.

Comment: What do you mean unintuitive? Do you think that users won't understand that the link actually links to another post?